# In two-dimensional polar coordinates,why does below approximate valid？

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, coordinate-systems, geometry

$$\Delta \hat r\approx \Delta \phi \hat \phi$$
where $\hat r$ and  $\hat \phi$ is the vector unit in two-dimensional polar coordinates.

I can't understand it when I am learning the Classical Mechanics by John R Tayler. I think the right of equation should be added r, since I think the longer r , the bigger $\Delta \hat r$, but it does't.

Who can show me how to understand the equation, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $\hat{r}$ unit vector is independent of the radial coordinate, so no perturbation of $r$ will change it. On the other hand, a change in $\phi$ will rotate it by $\Delta \phi$. So the new radial unit vector would be

$$ \hat{r}(\phi + \Delta \phi) = \cos (\Delta \phi) \hat{r} + \sin (\Delta \phi )\hat{\phi} $$

To first order, $\sin x \approx x$ and $\cos x \approx 1$, so

$$ \Delta \hat{r} = \hat{r}(\phi + \Delta \phi) - \hat{r}(\phi) \approx \Delta \phi \hat{\phi} $$